# Unable to create layer for CardView Android Transition

Tags: android, android-animation, android-transitions

I'm having a really weird issue with Android `Transition` API. I have a `sharedElement` an `ImageView` that I let the OS handle the `Transition` between these two elements. however I'm having this weird issue as showing in the **gif below**
[image: One SharedElement]

the only `element` that I'm `animating` is the `AvatarView` as you can see, however `onBackPressed` crash the app with this log

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create layer for CardView
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
```

The code that starts the `Activity`

first `Layout`

```
<com.fastaccess.ui.widgets.AvatarLayout
            android:id="@+id/avatarLayout"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:transitionName="@string/image_transition"/>
```

second `Layout`

```
<com.fastaccess.ui.widgets.AvatarLayout
            android:id="@+id/avatarLayout"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:transitionName="@string/image_transition"/>
```

And here is how I start the `Transition`

```
ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity,
sharedElement, ViewHelper.getTransitionName(sharedElement));
activity.startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
```

No more fancy code after this, except I'm calling `supportFinishAfterTransition`

Here is another **gif** but without `SharedElement Transition` & it does work fine. 
[image]

To be honest the **Crash log** does not tell much, but i can confirm its due to the `Comment TextView` is being *Large* even tho it has nothing to do with the `SharedElement` but it seems it is the cause to the *Crash* as per my tests.
It'll be great if anyone has encounter this before and found a way to fix it as i gave up.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Fix Attempting:

setting `android:transitionGroup="false"` on the `RowItem` `rootLayout` itself as if i did set it on the `ViewPager` or on the `RecyclerView` the same crash will happen.Another important step was returning `false` on `hasOverlappingRendering()` from the custom `TextView` class. but this causes the `ExitTransition` to have a flickery background color **Another Weird issue** I'll be digging more on this & won't accept this answer until i find a solution to the flickery background or someone else has a different approach to fix this.

**Edit**

The weird background is actually the `CardView` itself that holds the `CommentTextView`.

**Edit**

Actually, the `CardView` is the actual cause & not the long `TextView` I'v changed the CardView to `LinearLayout` as the root element of my row items and removed all the workarounds i did above and everything seems to be working fine. I'v no clue why would it cause the issue, I'm hopping someone could actually help & elaborate on why large `CardView` would cause this issue.